# Ошибка: DPI-1047: Oracle Client library cannot be loaded

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД Oracle, но скрипт не может найти `cx_Oracle`.  Вот сам скрипт:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect(‘DBNAME/testitout@www.xx.yy.zz:1521/yeppers’)
print(con.version)
con.close()
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
================= RESTART: C:\Python35\Connect_To_Oracle.py =================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Connect_To_Oracle.py", line 1, in <module>
   import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: 
    The specified module could not be found. See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html for help
```

ОС и версии:

- Intel Xeon CPU E7-4870 @ 2.40GHz
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
- Python 3.5

Что делал для установки `cx_Oracle`:

1. Скачал Instant Client (Basic Client) [отсюда](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html), а именно: instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0
2. Unzip.
3. Добавил новую системную переменную `ORACLE_HOME` и указал путь на `c:\Down\InstantClient`, где  распаковал.
4. Скачал и установил .whl файл по инструкции:

   - You have to download the whl file from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/  To do this, you need to know your version of Python and your type of processor.
   - You download into the scripts folder and then run pip install wheelfilename.whl

Почему эта ошибка? Что не хватает?

---

PS (прим. ред.):
В более новых версиях и при отсутствии клиента, исключение будет не в `import`:

```
$ python3 <<+++
import cx_Oracle
print (cx_Oracle.version)
print (cx_Oracle.clientversion ())
+++
7.2.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Python cx_Oracle Client Library Cannot Be Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45225918) от участника [@user8340926](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8340926/user8340926)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/45225918

Answer (score 2):

По указанному в инструкции к ошибке `DPI-1047` URL сказано, что `PATH` должен быть установлен на расположение библиотек *Instant Client*.
Также нужны правильные *VS Redistributable*.

**Обратите внимание**, что в ней не упоминается установка `ORACLE_HOME`.

Убедитесь, что *Instant Client* имеет ту же 32-битную или 64-битную архитектуру, что и Python.

Инструкции по установке `cx_Oracle` [находятся здесь](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html).

---

С помощью `cx_Oracle` начиная с версии 8 на Windows и MacOS (но не Linux), можно использовать [`init_oracle_client()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html), чтобы указать прямо в коде, где находятся библиотеки *Instant Client*. Это удобней, чем установка `PATH`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237960) от участника [@Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones)</sub>